# Multiple else if conditions true

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have multiple `elsif` conditions in a else if statement.

What is the flow of the statement if multiple conditions are true? So in the simplistic example below which serves as a demonstration only, is the the second elsif condition ever reached?

```
my $i = 1;

if ($i == 1){
}
elsif (i == 2){
}
elsif (i == 1){
}
else{
}
```

Comment: Tests stop once a condition succeeds, this means the second `$i==1` is never tested when `$i=1`.

Comment: I haven't written an else in five years. I can't think of an elsif.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy to try:

```
use feature ":5.10";

my $i = 1;

if ($i == 1) {
    say "A"; # this is the only branch executed
} elsif (i == 2) {
    say "B";
} elsif (i == 1) {
    say "C";
} else {
    say "D";
}
```

Each `elsif` is only considered if the previous conditions did not succeed. You can see that the comparisons are not even tried:

```
if ($i == 1) {
    say "A";
} elsif (i == 2/0) { # This doesn’t blow up since the comparison is never tried
    say "B";
} else {
    say "C";
}
```

Comment: (I think `2/0` used to die at compile-time because that's when `2/0` is evaluated, but the exception is deferred now.)

Answer (score 2):

The system starts at the if statement and checks the condition. If it is true, it executes the body of the statement and then skips over the remaining else and else if statements. If it is false, it moves down to the first else if statement listed. The same process occurs: check condition, if true execute body and skip over remaining else if and else statements; if false skip down to the next else if statement.

**In short**: the else if statements are chosen in order from the top down. So if you have two else if statements that would both be true, only the top one would be executed.

Answer (score 1):

First match will win other esle/elsif blocks are skipped.

No, the second `elsif` block will not be reached.